# editing in low res

Tags: edit-mode

I would like to know if I can edit with reduced files from 4k footage and when I'm done with my editing in low res, change folder so that Blender does the exact same editing but with the 4k footage in another folder. Is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: Don't think it's a duplicate - sounds like Olivier is asking about proxies, and not trying to render lower-res images.

Comment: Greg is right, this isn't a duplicate. i'm trying to edit in low res and then have blender do the same editing in high res.

Comment: please edit your question and be specific about what you want. Is this to do with the VSE? Compositor? It was only marked as duplicate because no one understands you :)